# How to tint peek&pop custom actions?

Tags: ios, 3dtouch, tintcolor

When pick&pop view is presented, custom actions (`UIPreviewAction` objects) are shown in default iOS blue color.
Is there any way they can be tinted in different color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS 11, what seems to work is adding in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.tintColor = MY_COLOR
```

I'm not sure if the same approach would work for pre-iOS11 versions, but here is what worked for me for pre-iOS11:

in `viewWillAppear` method of a preview controller (viewController which implements `previewActionItems` method add:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIView* container = [self.view superviewOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UIVisualEffectContentView")];
    container.tintColor = YOUR_COLOR;
}
```

The `superviewOfClass` method is implemented in `UIView+MyUtils` category:

```
- (UIView*) superviewOfClass:(Class)c
{
    UIView* parent = self;
    while ((parent = parent.superview))
    {
        if ([parent isKindOfClass:c])
        {
            return parent;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Use UITransitionView instead of _UIVisualEffectContentView for iOS12.